# How to use the rate limiter/throttle in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, soap, throttling, rate-limiting

I need a rate limiter to avoid attacks on my service. I've tried searching around but there are lots of examples for C# and not for VB. Is there any solution? or another way?

Comment: Although C# has picked up a few things that can't be done in VB, most things translate directly.  Being able to understand C# is an essential skill for .NET development.  Is there something specific you have problems with?